# Separate urls for child node with multiple parent nodes?

Tags: 6, nodes

I have a question. I am currently building a site with different sections (a content type with childrens of type normal-content), where some content is identical on parts of the site but some pages have their own version of the page. Se example below

section1/about_us (nid 45)
section2/about_us (nid 45)
section3/about_us (nid 62)
section4/about_us (nid 45)

The issue in my example is that when using pathauto to create the urls the url and the hierarchy is created correctly but only one of the nodes is treated as a parent in regards of the url. They all get the same url section1/about_us (except the one that is created separately). Which I think is the correct way to create the urls but in my case I need separate urls even if the page loaded is the same since it reflects a virtual hierarchy. Is there a way for me to hook into some function to let the pathauto create separate urls for each section?

Best regards,
Jocke

Comment: If this website is public facing I wouldn't recommend doing this. Search engines penalise duplicate content, and two separate resources with identical content (which is what you would be creating) would certainly class as that

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with Clive, [nodehierarchy](http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy) module should help you out on your issue.